# How to Connect Ethernet in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

So my Internet provider just gave me an username and password. How do I can connect to Ethernet to Linux ubuntu.

Comment: Do u mean connection with wifi or what?

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to connect Internet via Broadband connection. I Have username and just password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect your ethernet wire to the port at the back of your computer.
2. Fire up the terminal and type in sudo pppoeconf
3. It should detect your modem.
4. Keep on pressing enter. Fill in your user name and password when indicated.
5. It should be easy to stick on to defaults.
6. You should be prompted back to your terminal when it would say pppoe loaded.Simple. That's the end of terminal.
   Now go to System>Networking. Click on it .
7. Activate the Wired connection.
8. Highlight the wired connection and click on properties.
9. Check the box "enable the connection"

As reference from ask ubunto :
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://askubuntu.com/questions/100489/how-to-set-up-a-broadband-connection&ved=2ahUKEwiry8-R9rroAhXPiFwKHVZoD_kQFjACegQICxAN&usg=AOvVaw1RV4TfcbHa7PasJ0LNV1E_